# How can I set an audio strip in 2.8 so it plays according to where the playhead is in the timeline?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, audio

In 2.79 when I ticked under the playback menu, Audio Scrubbing, AV Sync and Frame drop, I knew that the timeline indicator was in sync with the audio.

Currently in 2.8 the timeline playhead is nowhere near the real audio, but lagging way behind, which makes the animation rather painful.

Answer (score 0):

I actually missed the AV Sync onption at the top of the playback menu.

Selecting AV sync,  makes things much better;)...  though still too jumpy, when compared to the same audio strip on 2.79. Is Frame drop the missing link or else?

Cheers